# Login not working with VueJS and Laravel

Tags: laravel, text, authentication, vuejs2

I am working on a login for my website. I added my form below. I activated the login route with Auth::routes();. With php artisan route:list I can see my route as well. But the problem is that every time I try to login, the login page just refreshes. How can I find out what is going wrong, is there a way to get a response from my post request in order to get some debug info? Any help is welcome!

```
 <div class="main-div">
    <div class="panel">
            <h2>Hello</h2>
        </div>
        <form id="Login" role="form" method="POST" action="/login">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf_token">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="forgot">
            <a href="reset.html">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
     </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you show me the controller and vue js code? why u use v:value: csrf_token if u didnt use axios?

Comment: I was just trying to do post request with login form. I have changed it to an axios request and that is working. But now I have to manually redirect to other page. On successfull login the response contains the complete html code of my redirected page indicated in Laravel:      postLogin() { 
         
          axios.post('/login', {
                  email: this.email,
                  password: this.password,
                  _token: this.csrf_token
          }).then(response => {
           router.push({ name: "Panel"})
          });
         }